# How does one calculate apsidial rotation after a spacecraft's radial burn?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion

I am researching orbital mechanics (for fun and knowledge) and I've come across a problem: How do I calculate the new orientation of the Apsis line (the major axis), periapsis, and apoapsis after a radial burn? I've searched and searched for answers to no avail. I can only find information on prograde, retrograde, and inclination burns.

---

Here's what I do know:

- Radial burns rotate the Apsis line (and the whole ellipse) about the planetary focus

---

I would greatly appreciate help with deriving equations, or finding resources to solve this problem.